# CSS Menus and JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, menu

This is my first ever post in a forum. Do guide me where necessary

I am trying to set up a template for basic webpage editing (using Wordpress) and having a lot of trouble with menus. The site is here: http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/

I managed to eventually set up a CSS only menu (3 level) which seemed to work ok, though I did not have control over floats (submenus always floated vertical and no matter what I altered I could not get them to float horizontal). Before anyone asks why I was trying to do that- it was to test myself and the code to see that it was set up correctly. Didn't quite do this.

Then I ignored this and pressed on to see if I could get some effects added to it through jQuery. I initialised jQuery correctly and added some code that I thought would give me a sliding drop down.

It seems to be ok in Chrome - but the 3rd level does not slide and thus falls back on CSS I think. In Internet Explorer 8, there is a flicker when I move to the 2nd level drop down and the 3rd level bounces up and down from zero height to full.

I can't even seem to replicate this on my local site. It just doesn't work at all there.

Can any kind soul give me any pointers? Maybe I am trying to run before I can walk but I fear that I have not even got the basics right with the CSS code.

Apologies but there is a bit of commented out code also as am trying to learn as I go. Those with _NULL after them had this added to get the jquery to kind of work as _NULL meant that the html no longer referenced them.

How could this code be better and how can I get good drop downs with jQuery to three levels?

Many thanks

Below is the jQuery but the css is also crucial to get right

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {/*normally loads in noconflickmode, so have to use this line to be able to use the $ sign*/
        ($("#menubar ul li").hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass("hover");
            $('ul:first',this).slideDown(400);
        },
        function(){
            $(this).removeClass("hover");
            $('ul:first',this).slideUp(400);
        });
        $("#menubar ul li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");
    });
</script>
```

So the CSS is

```
#menubar-outer { /*container box with no colour. Used to position inner div*/
    background-color: #D5CBA7;
    position: relative;/*Needs to be explicitly set for z-index*/
    z-index: 50;/*Needed for IE7*/
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0px 0;/*Use lower margin for lower line tab effect. Use a negative offset on left to align*/
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;/*CONTROLS overall position of menu. Right, left or center*/
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;*/
}
#menubar { /*inner container box..Sets space and fonts*/
    /*background-color:blue;*/
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
    margin: 0 0 0px 0px;/*for space around the menu first row*/
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: bottom;/*needed to remove automatic inline-block additional 5px margin*/    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
#menubar a {/*The element containing the words*/
    /*background-color: #dbdbdb; *//*color of main menu*/
    display: block; /*using block rather than inline makes entire block, not just the text clickable*/
    /*height: 15px;*//*CONTROLS height of menu item on first row together with "li li a" which controls for subsequent rows*/
    padding: 10px 15px; /*space around the menu items*/
    line-height: 15px;/*spacing between lines on same menu item*/
    text-align: left;/*CONTROLS centred menu items or left/right aligned. "a" element used rather than li which doesn't work in IE7. Affects drop downs so important*/
}

#menubar li li a {  /*Second and third level rows. */
    /*height: 30px;*/    /*Needed for styling different height on first row*/
    /*padding: 7px 6px;*//*Needed for styling different padding than first row*/
    /*background-color: #D5CBA7;*//*CONTROLS filled background color for dropdowns. Important because above active page highlights will override otherwise*/
}
#menubar li:first-child {
    border-left: none;/*accompanies divider&box line aboves. Use "none" if you are using seperators and add in e.g. "1px solid #c0c0c0"" if borders*/
}
#menubar li { /* fixes dimensions of all level menu elements. Turns menu into horizontal*/
    float: left;/*makes the menu horizontal. Needed above in "a" for ie6 but causes compatibility probs*/
    position: relative;/*need this to ensure that the following div can be absolutely positioned*/    /*width: 130px;*/ /*CONTROLS first row menu item spacing. Width needed for li rather than "a" to work in ie7*/
    margin: 0 0px 0 0;/*THIS creates gaps between items*/
    /*border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
     border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;/*Use border top right and bottom only if you want surrounding boxes*/
    border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;/*Use by itself  if you want dividers, together with above if seperated boxes or"none" for joined boxes (each box uses the folowing box's right border except the first child)*/
    /*border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
     -khtml-border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0px 0px;*/
}
#menubar li:last-child {
    border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;/*accompanies divider&box line aboves. Use "none" if you are using seperators and add in e.g. "1px solid #c0c0c0"" if borders*/
}
#menubar ul ul li:last-child {
    border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;/*accompanies divider&box line aboves. Use "none" if you are using seperators and add in e.g. "1px solid #c0c0c0"" if borders*/
}
#menubar ul ul li:first-child {
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;/*If boxes used on dropdown. Used to override border-top none below "li li"*/
    border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;/*If boxes used on dropdown. Use to override "li:first-child" on the previous level dropdown*/
}
#menubar ul ul li {/*Dropdown items*/
    background-color: #D5CBA7;/*KEEP as background color needed fir IE6 to select over another div*/
    left: -2px;/*CONTROLS for border. 0 if no border. -1px if border is 1px. Adjust together with "li" above, "li:first-child" above, "border" below on this ID and "top" and "left" on "ul ul li:hover ul"*/
    width: 130px;/*needed to make the whole line selectable*/
    margin: 0;/*Needed to reset dropdowns if margin used on first level*/
    border-top: none;
    border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;/*Use border right, bottom and left only if you want surrounding boxes. Also adjust "left" in this same ID (border top is "none")*/    /*border-left: none;/*Use "border-left:none" only  if you want dividers and for them to be removed on every sublevel*/
    /*border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     -khtml-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
}
#menubar ul ul, #menubar ul li:hover ul ul {  /* Hide all the dropdowns (submenus)  */
    display: none;
    /*visibility:hidden;*/
    position: absolute;/*absolute means that it is absolutely positioned to the 'relative' div before it*/
    left: 0px;/*needed for IE7*/
    z-index: 60;/*for hovering over itself*/
    width: 130px; /*CONTROLS width of colored background in dropdown levels. Needed to float left*/
}
#menubar ul li:hover ul_NULL {/*Second level submenus. Container box that the li's sit within and on top of. Displays when li are hovered on*/
    /*background-color:red;*/
    display: block;
}
#menubar ul ul li:hover ul {/*third level submenus.  Container box that the li's sit within and on top of. Displays when li are hovered on*/
    /*background-color:red;*/
    display:block;
    position: absolute;/*absolute means that it is absolutely positioned to the 'relative' div before it*/
    top: -2px;  /*CONTROLS for border. 0 positions at the top with no border or -1 for border*/
    left: 132px;/*CONTROLS width. Match to "li" if width given + BORDER + 1 BORDER. 100% positions 1 col over to right, incl margin.*/
    z-index: 60;/*for hovering over itself*/
    width: 130px; /*CONTROLS width of colored background in dropdown levels. Needed to float left*/
}
#menubar ul ul li:hover ul_NULL {/*third level submenus.  Container box that the li's sit within and on top of. Displays when li are hovered on*/
    /*background-color:red;*/
    display: block;
}
```

and finally the html

```
<div id="menubar-outer">
    <span id="menubar" class="linkclass-mainmenu">
        <!--span needs to be used for ie7 to be able to use text-align on variable width-->
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="page_item page-item-21">
                    <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/adventures-of-huckleberry-finn/">
                        Adventures of Huckleberry Finn
                    </a>
                    <ul class='children'>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-23">
                            <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/adventures-of-huckleberry-finn/conflict-between-civilization-and-natural-life/">
                                Conflict between civilization and natural life
                            </a>
                            <ul class='children'>
                                <li class="page_item page-item-22">
                                    <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/adventures-of-huckleberry-finn/conflict-between-civilization-and-natural-life/the-adventures-of-tom-sawyer/">
                                        The Adventures of Tom Sawyer
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-24">
                            <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/adventures-of-huckleberry-finn/intellectual-and-moral-education/">
                                Intellectual and Moral Education
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-31">
                    <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/contact-us/">
                        Contact Us
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-9">
                    <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/duke-and-the-king/">
                        Duke and the King
                    </a>
                    <ul class='children'><li class="page_item page-item-10">
                    <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/duke-and-the-king/conflict-between-civilization-and-natural-life/">
                        Conflict between civilization and natural life
                    </a>
                    </li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-12">
                            <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/duke-and-the-king/parodies-of-popular-romance-novels/">
                                Parodies of Popular Romance Novels
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-11">
                            <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/duke-and-the-king/the-hypocrisy-of-civilized-society/">
                                The Hypocrisy of Civilized Society
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-17">
                    <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/jims-escape/">
                        Jim&#8217;s escape
                    </a>
                    <ul class='children'>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-18">
                            <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/jims-escape/childhood/">
                                Childhood
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-19">
                            <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/jims-escape/conflict-between-civilization-and-natural-life/">
                                Conflict between civilization and natural life
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-20">
                            <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/jims-escape/reception/">
                                Reception
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="page_item page-item-5">
                    <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/mockery-of-religion/">
                        Mockery of Religion
                    </a>
                    <ul class='children'>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-8">
                            <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/mockery-of-religion/duke-and-the-king/">
                                Duke and the King
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-6">
                            <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/mockery-of-religion/jims-escape/">
                                Jim&#8217;s escape
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-7">
                            <a href="http://munchkingraphicdesign-uat.com/devsite/mockery-of-religion/life-in-st-petersburg/">
                                Life in St. Petersburg
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </span><!-- end #menubar -->
    <div class="clearfix">

    </div><!--Used when floating. Clearfix comes before closing div of non-floated element-->
</div><!--end #menubar-outer-->
```

## jsFiddle

Comment: #menubar ul li ul li -- means you have specified two levels... that's why it's not working on third level. do something like #menubar ul li ul.subUL where subUL is a ul class belonging to a subset of the first and inner children... make sure all the inner uls have class="subUL"

Comment: Thanks Robert! That helps that last line I think - but that is only to add the  symbol on the menu item to show that there are further sub-menus.

That first section I am not quite understanding. Do I need to double this code up and change it to account for the next level down also? Trying to mess around with it in jsfiddle now (just discovered it) but will probably be all weekend.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [**modified jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/neo108/XCGGB/) of your menu - with the working 3 level drop down menu in CSS.

I have tested it in Chrome, Firefox & IE and it works fine.

Hope it helps you. The code for the same is below...

**CSS**

```
#menubar-outer { 
    background-color: #D5CBA7;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
}
#menubar { 
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
#nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 7px 6px 0;
    line-height: 100%;
}
#nav li {
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0 0 8px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
}

/* main level link */
#nav a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding:  8px 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

/* main level link hover */
#nav .current a, #nav li:hover > a {
    background: #D5CBA7;
    color: #000;
}

/* sub levels link hover */
#nav li a {
    background: #D5CBA7;
    border: none;
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #AE953C;
}

/* dropdown */
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

/* level 2 list */
#nav ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 185px;
    position: absolute;
}
#nav ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav ul a {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-color: #000;
}

/* level 3+ list */
#nav ul ul {
    left: 181px;
    top: -3px;
}

#nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="menubar-outer">
    <span id="menubar" class="linkclass-mainmenu">
        <!--span needs to be used for ie7 to be able to use text-align on variable width-->
        <div class="menu">
            <ul id="nav">
            <li class="current"><a href="http://www.webdesignerwall.com">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com">My Projects</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com">N.Design Studio</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/wp-themes">WordPress Themes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/wallpapers">Wallpapers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/tutorials">Illustrator Tutorials</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.webdesignerwall.com">Web Designer Wall</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://jobs.webdesignerwall.com">Design Job Wall</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="http://icondock.com">IconDock</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://bestwebgallery.com">Best Web Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Multi-Levels</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Team</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sales</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Department</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sub-Level Item</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>   
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </span><!-- end #menubar -->
    <div class="clearfix">

    </div><!--Used when floating. Clearfix comes before closing div of non-floated element-->
</div><!--end #menubar-outer-->
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks a lot cleaner than mine. Will go over. Not 100% sure I can get all the classes in Wordpress (they are automatically assigned and think it gets more complicated to try to change these) but the learning will help me.